# Having troubles with threads and semaphors in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, semaphore, notify

I am new to threading and semaphors, and I have some problem in synchronizing threads. For example, in the following code I want to do a pretty simple thing. To let one thread run, while other waits. For example, if it starts with the first thread, I want the second to wait for the first one to finish and then start. I really don't know what am I doing wrong.
Here is the code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Semaphore binaren = new Semaphore(1);
        Runnable t1 = new T2(binaren);
        Thread a = new Thread(t1);
        Thread a2 = new T1(binaren);
        System.out.println(binaren.availablePermits());
        a.start();
        a2.start();
    }
}
class Work {

    private static int a = 4;
    public synchronized static void QQR(String s1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        System.out.println(s1+" : "+(a++));
    }

}
class T1 extends Thread
{
    Semaphore sem;
    public T1(Semaphore s1)
    {
        sem=s1;
    }
    public void run()
    {   
        synchronized(this)  {
            if(!sem.tryAcquire()){
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Work.QQR("T1");
            sem.release();
            notifyAll();
        }

    }


}
class T2 extends Thread
{
    Semaphore sem;

    public T2(Semaphore s1)
    {
        sem=s1;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    synchronized(this)  {
        if(!sem.tryAcquire()){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Work.QQR("T2");
        sem.release();
        notifyAll();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I know this is just test code, but you'd get ten times more readers if you didn't use `t1` and `t2`--and assign the `T2` instance to `t1` wtf?

Comment: As you're trying to understand `wait` and `notify` it doesn't apply, but normally using the concurrency classes allows you to avoid using the monitor primitives.

Comment: Well I am sorry for the messy code, I was just frustrated and post it unformated like that. I am new to stackoverflow, first time asking for  code help online. I will try to get better in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `notify` and `notifyAll` only wake up threads holding locks on the monitor being notified. But the `t1` and `t2` instances are waiting on themselves and are never awoken. You can have them wait on the semaphore for this simple test or introduce a new shared object to see how it works.

Use

```
sem.wait();
```

and

```
sem.notifyAll();
```

Comment: @user3344207 As you're trying to understand `wait` and `notify` it doesn't apply, but normally using the concurrency classes allows you to avoid using the monitor primitives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.join()` on the first thread so that second thread will wait till the execution of this instance is not completed.

Comment: Well yes, I can do the same thing with semaphors only, but the thing is I really want to understand how wait() and notify() work.

Comment: Using wait() you can wait the execution of any Thread for particular time/till you notify it.

Comment: Well that is the problem I am having. I can't understand why doesn't my code work. For example if thread a starts first, thread a2 will wait. When a finishes I use notify all and a2 should start running. Is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: if u use wait on t2 then it will wait till u apply notify on t2 or notifyall.